# How to handle python package?

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

background:
python 3.7.9 32-bit

```
file structure:
    Python_project
     |_main.py
     |_package_1
       |_ __init__.py
       |_class_obj_1.py
     |_package_2
       |_class_obj_1.py
       |_ __init__.py
```

In main.py

```
from .package_1.class_obj_1 import Class_obj_1
from .package_2.class_obj_2 import Class_obj_2
```

I still got a error

```
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Can anyone teach me what is the problem?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer it behind the main.py

```
from .package_1.class_obj_1 import Class_obj_1
from .package_2.class_obj_2 import Class_obj_2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your advice. I got error
  >>>>  Attempted relative import beyond top-level package
that's some problem here

Comment: did you add your packages in __init__.py?